# How to find out table lock or row lock in Sybase

Tags: locking, sybase

I have a stored procedure in Sybase, it's called by the Java code on a row by row insertion, how do I find out whether this SP is locking table or locking row? To check the underlying table properties or the SP itself?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp1
(@id_code             varchar(10), 
 @position_id         numeric(10,0)  OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO abc..table1(
            id_code,
            position_id
        )
        values (
            @id_code
            @position_id
        )        
    COMMIT

    SELECT @position_id = @@identity    
END
go
EXEC sp_procxmode 'dbo.sp1', 'unchained'
go
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sp1') IS NOT NULL
    PRINT '<<< CREATED PROCEDURE dbo.sp1 >>>'
ELSE
    PRINT '<<< FAILED CREATING PROCEDURE dbo.sp1 >>>'
```

Comment: Hi, Don't forget to upvote and/or accept helpful answers.  :?)

Answer (score 1):

The lock scheme for a table can be determined using the `lockscheme()` built in command.

```
lockscheme('tableName')
```

You can also specify `obj_id` and `dbid`.

[ASE 16 Documentation: lockscheme](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1600/doc/html/san1393050466007.html)